# Extract rows where the lists of columns contain certain values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    ID   AgeGroups        PaperIDs
0   1    [3, 3, 10]       [A, B, C]
1   2    [5]              [D]
2   3    [4, 12]          [A, D]
3   4    [2, 6, 13, 12]   [X, Z, T, D]
```

I would like the extract the rows where the list in the `AgeGroups` column has at least 2 values less than 7 and at least 1 value greater than 8.

So the result should look like this:

```
    ID   AgeGroups        PaperIDs
0   1    [3, 3, 10]       [A, B, C]
3   4    [2, 6, 13, 12]   [X, Z, T, D]
```

I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create helper `DataFrame` and compare by [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) and 
[`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html), then Series by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and chain masks by `&` for bitwise AND:

```
import ast
#if not lists
#df['AgeGroups'] = df['AgeGroups'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['AgeGroups'].tolist())
df = df[df1.lt(7).sum(axis=1).ge(2) & df1.gt(8).sum(axis=1).ge(1)]
print (df)
   ID       AgeGroups      PaperIDs
0   1      [3, 3, 10]     [A, B, C]
3   4  [2, 6, 13, 12]  [X, Z, T, D]
```

Or use `list comprehension` with compare numpy arrays, counts by `sum` and compare both counts chained by `and`, because scalars:

```
m = [(np.array(x) < 7).sum() >= 2 and (np.array(x) > 8).sum() >=1  for x in df['AgeGroups']]

df = df[m]
print (df)
   ID       AgeGroups      PaperIDs
0   1      [3, 3, 10]     [A, B, C]
3   4  [2, 6, 13, 12]  [X, Z, T, D]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple if else logic I wrote for each row using apply function, you can also use list comprehension for row.

```
data = {'ID':['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'AgeGroups':[[3,3,10],[2],[4,12],[2,6,13,12]],'PaperIDs':[['A','B','C'],['D'],['A','D'],['X','Z','T','D']]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def extract_age(row):
    my_list = row['AgeGroups']
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    if len(my_list)>=3:
        for i in my_list:
            if i<7:
                count1 = count1 +1
            elif i>8:
                count2 = count2+1
    if (count1 >= 2) and (count2 >=1):
        print(row['AgeGroups'],row['PaperIDs'])


df.apply(lambda x: extract_age(x), axis =1)
```

Output

```
[3, 3, 10] ['A', 'B', 'C']
[2, 6, 13, 12] ['X', 'Z', 'T', 'D']
```